# Экранирование знака # в правиле rewrite nginx

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx, rewrite

**Задача:**

nginx должен менять урл /app/555 на /#app/555 и отправлять на бекенд сервер.

**Текущая конфигурация nginx:**

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name www.mydomain.com;
location / {
  proxy_pass http://my-backend;
}

location /app/ {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ "/\\#$1" break;
  proxy_pass http://my-backend;
}
```

}

**Nginx  выдает вот такую ошибку:**

```
    Bad request For request 'GET /\%23app/1' [Illegal character in path at index 1: /\%23app/1]
```

Подскажите как правильно экранировать  символ "#" ?

Comment: Вы туда именно `%23` поставьте, а не решетку.

Comment: Нельзя решётку использовать: она отделяет анкор (ссылку) от остальной части url.

Answer (score 1):

согласно [rfc1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> The character "#" is unsafe and should
>      always be encoded because it is used in World Wide Web and in other
>      systems to delimit a URL from a fragment/anchor identifier that might
>      follow it.

вольный перевод:

> символ "#" является «опасным» (*unsafe*) и должен всегда быть закодирован, потому что он используется в *world wide web* (*www*) и в других
>   системах для отделения *url* от фрагмента или якоря, который может следовать за ним.

---

под «закодирован» подразумевается — «заменён на [строку `%23`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)».

т.е., например, так:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ "/%23$1" break;
```

---

но, скорее всего, такое преобразование на самом деле не требуется. вероятно, «щелчок» такому *url-у* обрабатывается *javascript-ом*, а не сервером (возможно, при этом какие-то запросы к серверу и формируются этим *javascript-ом*, но они вряд ли содержат символ `#`).

Comment: к сожалению нет :(
пишет:
Action not found
For request 'GET /%2523app/1'

 т.е. он не понял что /%23 это #

Comment: а это вы уже с кодом, который это написал, разбирайтесь. // **и вообще**: с чего вы взяли, что в url-е **действительно** должнен быть символ решётка? возможно, вы увидели его на сгенерированной странице? так браузер и не отправляет серверу ту часть url-а, который идёт после решётки. на новомодных сайтах «щелчок» по такому url-у обрабатывается javascript-ом, который может проделать какие-то действия на странице, а может и сделать какой-нибудь запрос к серверу. естественно, не содержащий никаких решёток.

Comment: мне нужен урл вида  /#url/111 для angular'a

Comment: @Rurik, посмотрите на запросы, которые **действительно** отправляет ваш браузер «бэкэнд»-серверу. я уверен, что на сервер отправляется (если вообще отправляется) вовсе не `/#url/111`.

Comment: @Rurik nginx, скорее всего, # и всё, что после него, и не получает вовсе. Т. е. для него это запрос на `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Как мне объяснили на nginx форуме:

> Часть URL начиная с # имеет смысл только для браузера и на сервер не
>   передается. С точки зрения сервера - это некорректный URL. 
>   И на самом деле мне нужен редирект.

Итак сейчас работает вот так:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my-backend;
  }

  location /app/ {
    rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ "/#app/$1" permanent;
  }
}
```